# rename output files with iteration number and input with gnu parallel

Tags: gnu, gnu-parallel

I have a list of files (data1.txt, ... ,data6.txt) and I want to run the same commands on them 3 times as example. I am using gnu parallel

I want as output files: `1data1.txt, 2data1.txt, 3data1.txt, ... , 2data6.txt, 3data6.txt.`

I tried:

```
for i in $(seq 3); do parallel -j 8 'myCommand data{}.txt > results/out/{$i}data{}.txt' ::: 1 2 3 4 5 6; done
```

but my output files are : `{}data1.txt, ...., {}data6.txt`

I've tried different possibilities but I don't have the expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GNU Parallel's feature of making combinations:

```
parallel -j 8 myCommand data{2}.txt '>' results/out/{1}data{2}.txt' ::: 1 2 3 ::: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

If your CPU has 8 threads you can leave out `-j8`. This is a good idea, if you later are going to run it on a bigger system.

You can also use `--results` (requires version >20170222):

```
parallel --results results/out/{1}data{2}.txt myCommand data{2}.txt ::: 1 2 3 ::: 1 2 3 4 5 6 >/dev/null
```

Comment: Hello.. Thank you